# mysql: automatically convert seconds to hours for some columns

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am importing some `csv` data into `mysql5.7`.

Some columns have some time values, in seconds.

Since I cannot manipulate the `.csv` files, is there a way for those columns to be converted to hours just after the insertions (and before any other triggers are executed, given that there are already several `AFTER_INSERT` triggers running on this data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that seems to do the job:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `database_name`.`table_name_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SET new.my_field = floor(new.my_field/3600);

END
```

Just need to repeat the `SET` line for all fields required;